# Dart json serializable fails with custom builder and build.yaml file

Tags: dart, json-serializable, build-runner

I am currently developing my own code generator using the `source_gen` library in dart as a separate library.
At first this is the `build.yaml` file I used for it:

```
builders:
  fields_generator:
    import: "package:sculptor/fields_builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["fieldBuilder"]
    build_extensions: {".dart": [".json"]}
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: source
```

and everything worked as expected both in the library and in the project using it.

I want to use `json_serializable` in the generator library and when I try to run the `build_runner` I encounter one of two problems:

1. If I add the `json_serializable` builder to my `build.yaml` file like this:

```
builders:
  fields_generator:
    import: "package:sculptor/fields_builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["fieldBuilder"]
    build_extensions: {".dart": [".json"]}
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: source

targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:json_serializable:
        enabled: true
```

then the build runner throws an error

```
[WARNING] lib/src/models/mason_params.dart:3:6: Error: Error when reading 'lib/src/models/mason_params.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'mason_params.g.dart';
     ^
lib/src/models/mason_params.dart:3:6: Error: Can't use 'lib/src/models/mason_params.g.dart' as a part, because it has no 'part of' declaration.
part 'mason_params.g.dart';
     ^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 3.1s

[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
```

I tried adding my custom builder to the `targets` and defining `runs_before` option to the `json_serializable` builder but neither had success.

2. If I change my `build.yaml` to not contain my custom builder:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:json_serializable:
        enabled: true
```

then `build_runner` successfully builds the `.g.dart` files, but the project using my library doesn't build the files my custom generator should generate.